# Https POST request. 200 in postman 400 in code

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I tried to call an endpoint.

- Requests called via Postman ended fine.
- Requests called via **Axios** or **node-fetch** library were all ending with 400.

Firstly I tried to match my headers 1:1 with Postman... then, my idea was to compare these requests in **Fiddler**. Unfortunately, I was able to see there only requests from postman.

- Why I can't see my 400 requests in fiddler? *(maybe I am missing some
  settings there)*
- What can potentionaly cause this **400 - Bad request** issue?
  *(or any tips for investigation)*

Example fake request.

```
const emailRequest: EmailRequest = {
  replyTo: 'test',
  subject: 'test',
  text: 'test',
};

fetch('https://someaddress.com/sendemail',
        {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
            Date: 'Tue, 19 Apr 2022 04:59:50 GMT',
            server: 'Apache', 
            'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',            
            'X-Correlation-Id': 'b2d3808a-a9da-49a2-97eb-e3a222624062',
            'x-frame-options': 'DENY', 
            'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', //check
            Authorization:
              'Bearer (my bearer)',            
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(emailRequest),          
        },
      )
```

Thank you very much for your time and ideas.

Comment: possibly stop adding response headers in a request - `access-control-allow-*` headers have no place in a request, and that's not how you deal with CORS issues - `'content-length': '0',` ... but you're sending content - that is probably the main issue

Comment: Thank you, I removed all of the 'access-control-allow-*'  headers, so as 'content-lenght': '0'. But 400 still persist.  ...ps. I'll edit my question acccordingly

Comment: well, there's probably a bunch more headers etc you're doing wrong

Comment: Postman has a copy code option, which might be helpful, [here's how](https://dev.to/praneetnadkar/generating-code-to-call-a-request-from-postman-4h75) to use it. And if that still fails to work, then it's a CORS issue.

Comment: Yes. Actually, this helped me a lot!  Now I have generated 200 fetch request. 
ps. The article you mentioned is slightly dated. And for newer versions of Posman, the "Code" button is located inside of the right tab. Nevertheless, Thank you for mentioning this option.